# Can A Header Be Added & Body Modified In A Salesforce SOAP Response?

Tags: web-services, soap, salesforce, apex-code

From doing some testing on SOAP requests to a webservice I created in Salesforce  I note the response returned is of the following format.

Note my request function I called is GetMsgRQ

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/MyIntegrationServices">
<soapenv:Body>
<GetMsgRQResponse>
<result>
        <acctId>001J000000leVpEIAU</acctId>
        <acctName>MyTest</acctName>
     </result>
  </lGetMsgRQResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Relating to this I wonder is it possible to add a SOAP:Header?
Also I note the response has created an element "GetMsgRQResponse"  (adding "Response" to "GetMsgRQ".  Is it possible to create/specify the SOAP:Body without this occuring?  Can I just set what the whole SOAP body response will be or will Salesforce always add such additional elements as the "GetMsgRQResponse" here and "result"?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.  I know I can use a HTTP Request to send a full SOAP envelope but for my requirement I need to just provide a response instead of doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can directly add any kind SOAP headers in an Apex defined WebService methods.

If you have absolutely no other option you could construct your own custom SOAP response via a REST web service (via @RestResource annotation) but that is a pretty ugly solution.